# "Cannot read property 'node' of undefined" Error when accessing data from an array in my state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, loops, axios

Hi the im construction an app which pulls images from instagram using axios. I have managed to put the image files into an array called 'posts' in my state. I have no trouble looping through this array to return the JSX of each image. But when I try to access a specific element in that array ie.[2] or [3] I just get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined
```

Here is what the functioning loop looks like:

```
const posts = this.state.posts.map((post, id) => {
            const image = post.node.display_resources[0].src     
            console.log(post);
 })
```

In the log this returns: {node: {…}}

And when I log: post.node I get all of it's contents which is what I want.

However even though when I log: this.state.posts[0] I get the same:  {node: {…}}

When I try: this.state.posts[0].node I just get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching the data inside a `componentDidMount` lifecycle method the data will be available after the first mount which means when the component renders for the first time `this.state.posts` is still and empty array.

You should be checking if the data is available and `this.state.posts` is populated then you should be accessing the data.

Example..

```
if (this.state.posts.length) { 
  console.log(this.state.posts[0].node) // will log the data
}
```

Comment: Amazing stuff! Fixed my problem and learnt something new! Thanks!